# Principal Divisors of rational function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$  be a nonsingular curve. Let $k$ be algebraically closed field. If $f$ is a rational function on $X,$ then the principal divisors of $f$ is defined by $(f) = \sum_{P\in X}\nu_{P}(f)P,$ where $\nu_{P}$ represent the valuation at P. My question is how this sum is finite if $k(X)$ is different from $k(t).$ I got the idea only for $k(t).$ Thanks

Comment: See Hartshorne Lemma II.6.1 (which works in much greater generality). The basic point is that closed subsets of varieties (or Noetherian schemes) have only finitely many irreducible components.

Comment: Thank you Asal Beag Dubh.